# ElasticSearch "match" for several words?

Tags: elasticsearch

I did a bool query :

```
...
"bool":{
   "should" : [
    {"match": {"Process.Name": "eu.customers" }},
    {"regexp": {"Process.Name": ".*customers_all" }}
  ]
}
...
```

I maybe found out that spaces in the match clause could be interpreted by OR ???

So will I get the same results with :

```
...
{"match": {"Process.Name": "eu.customers customers_all" }}
...
```

?

If yes, the documentation is very poor in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

It's a little ambiguous but it hinted at by:

> If you need to know which of the clauses in the bool query matched the
>   documents returned from the query, you can use named queries to assign
>   a name to each clause.

I think you either need to look at:

1. The "must" clause
2. Qualify the "should" with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html

Answer (score 0):

I did a little test and match clause works as exactly you are expecting it to.

[image: match cluase]

```
PUT t2


PUT t2/_doc/1
{
  "Process.name":"eu.customers"
}

PUT t2/_doc/2
{
  "Process.name":"customers_all"
}

GET t2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Process.name": "eu.customers customers_all"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931472,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "t2",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "Process.name" : "eu.customers"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "t2",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "Process.name" : "customers_all"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I suspect your analyzers on the field `Process.name` are creating inverted index in a way that the match query doesnt match. Try to analyze the field and see how the inverted index are created.

```
GET indexname/_analyze
{
  "field": "Process.name",
  "text": ["eu.customers"]
}

GET indexname/_analyze
{
  "field": "Process.name",
  "text": ["customers_all"]
}
```

Comment: The Process table doesn't contain any index  
Yes match counts are identical in both cases  
Can we conclude that the "match" suppose an implicit OR ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html  -  so the OR is implicit  - 
`{"match": {"Process.Name": "eu.customers customers_all" }}` is equivalent to 
`{"match": {"Process.Name": { "query" : "eu.customers customers_all", "operator" : "or" }}}`

Comment: Yes. `OR` is the default operator